# Synonymize and merge the tags [be] and [to-be]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we merge and synonymize the tags [be](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/be) and [to-be](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-be)?

Comment: And make 'to-be' the main one? Just 'be' is way too short to understand.

Comment: Given the state of the tag system, nothing about it is easy to understand, and any time spent on revising it is wasted.

Comment: Title suggestion: "Retag to [be], and not [to-be]"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I'm not sure whether we want to do (manual) retagging. Merging tags can do this automatically

Comment: @wythagoras The title was meant as a pun. :)