# Let's synonymize "to be" tag with "be" tag. [Completed]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I have suggested [to-be](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-be) be synonymized with [be](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/be). Related Meta post by @wythagoras:

[Synonymize and merge the tags [be] and [to-be]](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7968/synonymize-and-merge-the-tags-be-and-to-be)

> https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/be/synonyms (It requires four upvotes)

Please upvote if you agree with it after clicking on the link above and downvote if you don't.

> Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Additional question: Is there any review queue to check those suggestions?

Comment: The entire list of current synonym suggestions is at http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms It is not integrated into the review queue page.

Comment: @Mitch Ah... I see. No pending suggestion, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes. Two problems: that link is hard to get to and once you get there are few things that are allowed to anybody. You can still edit tag descriptions though.

Comment: I've been here forever with good rep, and I only had one item 'pending' (the one you linked to) and even then, with a voting widget, it told me I couldn't vote. That is not a good UX if others are having similar problems.

Comment: Rathony, yes, that is the mechanical reason. The design decision to make that rule has been discussed at length on meta.SE with little resolution as far as I can see (or rather no one cares enough to change anything). There are so many tags created that it is hard for any person to have enough rep (rare tags seem correlated with low rep users).

Comment: The tag synonym system is simply clunky and awkward unless (like SO) you have lots of people who can vote on these things; usually, we end up just waiting for a moderator to sort it out or for people to actually notice one of these posts.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Yes, indeed. And ELU tags are not very clear-cut and there are many useless, unnecessary and overlapping tags here.

Comment: @Rathony I know, it's horrible! I know other sites do organised clean-up sessions; could we try something like that?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey As you well know, I don't have any authority to say "yes" or "no", but I am very sure not many users care so much about tags including myself. It's more  important to tag new questions correctly than cleaning up the tags in the past. BTW, I started to delete the correction tag, 5 posts per day.

Comment: @Rathony Yes, I saw your comment there, great work. I take your point that not many people care that much about the tags, however, EL&U's are so sprawling and random that we need a community effort. I'm going to ask in chat to see if one of the mods is interested.

Comment: I can't vote on the to-be synonym and honestly I am not entirely sold on the other one. I think we should have a post in which we can debate the comparison - differences synonym. The (admittedly bad) tag description does not sound like those two should be synonyms to me.

Comment: @Helmar I knew someone will raise that issue. Some questions tagged under "comparison" are about comparatives and I agree we need to have some discussion about it. Fair point. I edited out the link.

Comment: @Rathony I would rather make all questions of comparison off-topic across the board. The greatest majority can be answered with "dictionaries are free these days, and the differences are exactly the differences you can see between their dictionary definitions" (which of course OP has never bothered to consult) and the remaining ones which could be answered by a well-read speaker with an ear for nuance tend to cross over in POB territory, as no one ever seems to put in the work to substantiate the nuances with examples from literature or references to external authorities.

Comment: @Rathony At the very least we should aggressively VtC any "what's the difference?" questions which don't quote the relevant dictionary definitions directly and then make an attempt to compare them, highlighting any doubts which remain. And I when I say that I mean by the actual OP himself, not by well-intentioned regulars who are effectively editing in the answer to OP's question into the question itself!

Comment: @Rathony Maybe I'll post a Meta-question about what our foundational principles and ethics are (or should be), and we can work backwards from there. It seems to me not everyone is on board with the fundamental principle of "it's OK for OPs to be ignorant [that's why they're here!], but **not ok to be lazy**". Students enrich a community; parasites kill it.

Comment: @DanBron: I really don't understand why the perceived "laziness" of certain questioners matters so much to some people. I'm interested in reading and writing interesting questions and interesting answers. I couldn't care less about the character of the questioners. My only objection to edits adding research is that they may not reflect the actual understanding of the OP, who still has control over the accepted answer (and who may edit the question again later, which in a worst-case scenario may invalidate existing answers).